# “Chacun en ce qui lui/le concerne”

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, prépositions

Laquelle des expressions suivantes est correcte ?

> chacun en ce qui `lui` concerne

ou

> chacun en ce qui `le` concerne

Le contexte qui m'intéresse est celui-ci:

> Un ensemble de travailleurs sont chargés de faire du travail, chacun en ce qui lui/le concerne.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il est question de savoir si *concerner* prend un complément d'objet direct ou plutôt indirect.

Dans le premier cas la série de pronoms préverbaux serait :

> me, te, **le**, la, nous, vous, les

Dans le deuxième ce serait :

> me, te, **lui**, nous, vous, leur

Comme tu peux le voir, ni *me* ni *te* ne peuvent aider à répondre vu qu'ils apparaîssent dans les deux séries.

À la place, il faut se baser sur un article de dictionnaire, comme celui-ci:

> **concerner** *transitif* [..]
>
> 1. Toucher, intéresser sous tel ou tel rapport en parlant des choses.
>
>    - *Cela **concerne** vos intérêts.*
>        [..]
>    - *Cette affaire **concerne** chacun de nous.*
>
> <sup>([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/concerner#Fran.C3.A7ais))</sup>

Notons que les objects verbaux « vos intérêts » et « chacun de nous » ne sont pas précédés par des prépositions. C'est un test facile à partir duquel on peut conclure qu'il s'agit d'objets directs.* De plus, les dictionnaries utilisent *transitif indirect* ou quelque terme du genre pour [l'autre type](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/parler#Verbe).

De ce fait on optera pour *le*, pas *lui*, et pour toute la série de pronoms directs.

---

<sub>* Ce test ne marche pas dans l'autre sens par contre : *de* peut précéder un objet direct.</sub>

Comment: Enfin ma réponse est un peu contradictoire : Je dis qu'il faut se baser sur le dictionnaire mais c'est des données et non sur l'article même que je tire ma conclusion. Oh well ...

Answer (score 3):

Comme l'indique Luke [dans sa réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/27071/79), *concerner* est transitif direct, *le* est donc le bon choix de pronom.

Il y a cependant un autre problème dans cette formulation. *En ce qui concerne [quelqu'un ou quelque chose]* est utilisé pour changer le sujet de la conversation. C'est un groupe prépositionel qui introduit une proposition. Par exemple:

> En ce qui concerne le chat, nous l'avons laissé au voisin.

Ce n'est pas possible de l'utiliser de cette façon dans l'exemple donné (ni même avec *chacun* de façon générale, *chacun* ne pouvant pas être un nouveau sujet de conversation). La formulation idiomatique serait:

> Un ensemble de travailleurs ont été chargés de faire du travail. Chacun fait ce qui le concerne.

Answer (score 2):

En ce qui le concerne :)
(En ce qui me concerne, en ce qui te concerne ...)

Answer (score 1):

De l'utilisation de *chacun*... On dit :

```
Chacun en ce qui le concerne...
```

Comme on dirait :

```
Lui en ce qui le concerne...
```

pourtant *chacun* fait référence à un pluriel mais où chaque personne de ce pluriel est considérée de manière individuelle. C'est particulier. Le pronom réflexif est bien *le*, pas *les*, ni *lui*.
On peut dire :

```
Chacun, en ce qui le concerne lui, ...
```

pour une forme d'insistance sur le caractère individuel du choix, mais à l'oral.