# Utilizing Pronouns Correctly

Tags: pronoms, pronoms-relatifs, pronoms-personnels, pronoms-interrogatifs

I'm trying to figure out which pronouns to use for these examples... let me know if I'm on the right track:

Tu vois Jean-Paul là-bas ?
—Oui, je **lui** vois.

As-tu envoyé une lettre à Charlotte ?
—Oui, je **la** ai envoyé une longue lettre la semaine dernière.

—As-tu regardé la télé hier soir ? 
 —Non, je ne **le** ai pas regardée du tout. J’avais trop de devoirs!

—Parles-tu à tes amis de tes problèmes ?
—Oui, je **ai en** parle.

Apparently all of my answers are wrong... please help

Answer (score 2):

If the pronoun replaces a third person direct object, it is ***le*** or ***la*** at the singular, depending on the gender, and ***les*** if a plural. If the pronoun replaces an indirect object, we use ***lui*** at the singular and ***leur*** at the plural.

> - *Je vois Jean-Paul.* direct object : *Je **le** vois*.
> - *J'ai envoyé une lettre **à** Charlotte* : Indirect object: *Je **lui** ai envoyé une lettre*
> - *Je n'ai pas regardé la télé* : Direct object : *Je ne **l**'ai pas regardée.* (***l'*** for ***la*** before a vowel)
> - *Tu a parlé **à** tes amis **de** tes problèmes* : Two cases here: the first pronoun replaces an indirect plural object, so ***leur*** is used, the second pronoun replaces something introduced by the préposition *de* so it's always *en* : *Je **leur** **en** ai parlé.*

See also: [“Chacun en ce qui lui/le concerne”](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27062/chacun-en-ce-qui-lui-le-concerne/27071#27071)

Answer (score 2):

**I** — Tu vois Jean-Paul là-bas ?
 — Oui, je lui vois.

*correction:* Oui, je **le** vois.

The COD form is "le" for masculine nouns, "la" for feminine

**II** — As-tu envoyé une lettre à Charlotte ?
 — Oui, je la ai envoyé une longue lettre la semaine dernière.

*correction:* Oui, je **lui** ai envoyé une longue lettre la semaine dernière.

*or*

Oui, je **lui en** ai envoyé une longue la semaine dernière.

"Lui" is the form for the COI and it is used both for the masculine and feminine antecedents. In the second possibility the pronoun "en" stands for "lettre".

**III** — As-tu regardé la télé hier soir ?
 — Non, je ne le ai pas regardée du tout. J’avais trop de devoirs !

*correction:* — Non, je ne **l'** ai pas regardée du tout. J’avais trop de devoirs !

The pronoun is really "la", as you supposed, however, before a vowel sound it must have its elided form, which is "l" and it is then separated from the word that follows by an apostrophe.

**IV** — Parles-tu à tes amis de tes problèmes ?
 — Oui, je ai en parle.

*correction:* Oui, je **leur** en parle.

Here, the COI plural pronoun is missing; it is the same for all genders and its form is "leur".
There is also an incomprehensible error but the pronoun "en" is right. The tense used in the question is the present, the particular sort being "présent d'habitude"; therefore, if the answer is a confirmation of the action, as the introducing "oui" indicates, the tense must be the same. If the answer had been in the negative, then the tense could have been another one, but then the sentence would not be logical unless ther is a supplement of information (*for instance, as in* "Non, je leur en ai parlé par le passé mais plus maintenant.").